# Remove rows with inverse value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove those rows that have values that cancel each other.

[image]

In this example, I should only get:

[image]

There is now way of joining rows besides value, all other fields can be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `NOT EXISTS`. And inverting the number with `* -1`

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table t2
  WHERE t2.Value * -1 = t1.Value —- when a negative value equals a positive value or a positive value equals a negative
  —- other join conditions 
)
```

Comment: @user9964838 . . . That solves it until you find an id that has multiple rows with the same values.